# why this regex does not work in powershell?

Tags: c#, regex, powershell

```
$pattern = 'trigger(.+?)(\r|\n|\r\n){2}'
Write-Host "PATTERN $pattern"
Write-Host ("- trigger: blah`n blah`n blah blah`n`n not blah" -replace $pattern, "trigger: none")
```

Output should be "- trigger: none not blah"

Comment: This regex does not match for your input string [see here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=trigger%28.%2b%3f%29%28%5cr%7c%5cn%7c%5cr%5cn%29%7b2%7d&i=-+trigger%3a+blah%60n+blah%60n+blah+blah%60n%60n+not+blah). As far as I see your input does not contain a newline but the regex forces one (even if this pattern looks a bit strange). Try using `trigger(.+?)[\r\n]*`.

Comment: why do you tag C# for a powershell-question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

- `.+` matches everything except for newlines, use the inline flag `(?s)` or a modified dot `[\S\s]+`
- \r\n is the Windows line break and `\n` *unix; therefore it is best to make `\r` optional `?`: `(\r?\n)`

```
$pattern = 'trigger([\s\S]+?)(\r?\n){2}'
Write-Host "PATTERN $pattern"
Write-Host ("- trigger: blah`n blah`n blah blah`n`n not blah" -replace $pattern, "trigger: none")
```

> `- trigger: none not blah`